# Solr - getting exact results by field

Tags: solr

i am relativly new to solr. I have a question regarding searching specific values in a query. Maybe it's a misunderstanding of the solrconfig and the requesthandler.

My solrcfg looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
<luceneMatchVersion>5.2.0</luceneMatchVersion>
<requestHandler name="get_window_results" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">dismax</str>
    <str name="qf">manufacturers_name^10.0 products_name^10.0 id_shop_color_ii^10.0 id_shop_color_i^10.0 id_shop_color_iii^10.0 ID^1.0</str>
    <str name="pf">products_name</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers"/>
</config>
```

My Searchquery Looks like this:

```
solr/window_search/select?q=id_shop_color_ii:"2"&wt=json&indent=true&qt=get_window_results
```

In the result, i expect to see everything with `id_shop_color_id_ii` and the matching value of `2`. And then everything else, that might have a 2 in any other of the three color fields. However, my first result looks like this:

```
"id_shop_color_i": 2,
"shop_color_short_i": "braun",
    "shop_color_bez_i": "braun",
    "id_shop_color_ii": 0,
    "shop_color_short_ii": "",
    "shop_color_bez_ii": "",
    "id_shop_color_iii": 0,
    "shop_color_short_iii": "",
```

This makes no sense to me as i know for a fact that i have `id_shop_color_ii` with a value of `2`. However, they are not even lsited umong the first 50 results. Does anyone know, where my mistake is or if i have a problem in the basic understanding of the solrcfg?

Thanks
KR Adi

Comment: In your `schema.xml` file, what is the field type for `id_shop_color_ii`?

Comment: Hi, it's an integer.


`<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

....
<field name="id_shop_color_ii" type="int" indexed="true"    stored="true" />`

Comment: Instead of `q=id_shop_color_ii:"2"` in your query, try `q=2` (leave the rest of the query intact). The configuration of your dismax handler will use its `qf` setting to search for `2`.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. I'd just used this, changed the boosting and it was done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it worked for you. I went ahead and expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the dismax query parser as you are in your `get_window_results` handler, you can just pass it your query term and it will search against the weighted fields as defined in the handler. In your handler, that will include the `id_shop_color_id_ii` field. So you just need to change your query to this...

```
solr/window_search/select?q=2&wt=json&indent=true&qt=get_window_results
```